# Low FPS if camera is to close to the mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a small scene with 8 trees (every tree consists of 3k tris). It's okay when mesh scale is 0.5 and the trees are quite small: [image]
But with the default scale it looks like this (FPS decreased by half): [image]
I also use shaders for the wind effect. I've tried to use default shader, but it doesn't help. So if camera is close enough to the mesh it causes lags.

Shader code:

```
twigDefault.onBeforeCompile = function ( shader ) {
    shader.uniforms.time = { value: 0 };
    shader.vertexShader = 'uniform float time;\n' + shader.vertexShader;
    shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
        '#include <begin_vertex>',
        [
            'float theta = sin( time + position.y ) / 300.0;', //300
            'float c = cos( theta );',
            'float s = sin( theta );',
            'mat3 m = mat3( c, 0, s, 0, 1, 0, -s, 0, c );',
            'vec3 transformed = vec3( position ) * m;',
            'vNormal = vNormal * m;'
        ].join( '\n' )
    );
    meshes.tree.shader = shader;
};
```

In render():

```
if (meshes.tree.shader) {
    meshes.tree.shader.uniforms.time.value = performance.now() / 1000;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your app is _pixel-limited_, which material/fragment shader are you using to draw the trees?
Is the wind applied during the vertex pass or the fragment pass?

Comment: @neeh I've added shader code to the post.

Comment: there is more to it than your injection, it's doing some kind of transparency, lots of overdraw?

Comment: @pailhead I change twig material if player is not visible under the tree. But I already tried to remove this function, it doesn't affect FPS.

Comment: @Kittyhawk I wouldn't be too worried about the vertex shader since the scale of the tree won't change the number of vertices processed.
However, can you provide us the code for setting up the material/fragment shader? Or maybe the model itself?

Comment: @neeh Hm, I've already added all shader code to the post. There is also a similar shader for the customDepthMaterial. You can download .json file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/msbeyi4ai7rbox3/models.zip?dl=0).

Comment: I just tried to build a forest with your tree model and was able to reproduce the problem, even with the most basic shader, lighting disabled, shadow maps disabled, no anisotropy... I think the main problem is that when you zoom on the leaves, you have 1k faces of ~200x200 pixels stacked up on the screen and the detph test doesn't seem to help that much.
I would recommend taking lower poly models (2k faces seems a lot for this trunk), or keeping small trees... you can also look at [instancing](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html) if you plan to put a lot of trees

Comment: @neeh Thanks for your help. The best solution is to reduce the number of trees and use lower poly meshes.